# nice fonts for the classical sequence spaces?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, calligraphy

I have the problem that I want to have nice looking math symbols for the classical sequence spaces like Schwartz space, convergent sequences, sequences with finitely many non-zero members etc. I like the `\ell^p` for p-summable sequences but want some calligraphic looking ones for the others as well. Currently, I use the calligra package with some experimental (and still improvable) scaling. It produces a rather OK `c_0` and `c` but the `f` does not match at all. Any suggestions how to improve that?

[image]

here's a sample of code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calligra}          % used for sequence spaces
%
% Stuff for sequence spaces, more dirty than quick:
% use the calligra fonts for this, scaled a bit larger, only the "f"
% is too large...
%
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{calligra}{m}{n}{<->s*[2.2]callig15}{}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcalligra}{T1}{calligra}{m}{n}
% convergent sequences
\newcommand{\seqc}           {\mathcalligra{c}}
% zero sequences
\newcommand{\seqcn}          {\mathcalligra{c}_0}
% finite sequences  
\newcommand{\seqf}{{\mathcalligra{f}}}
% Schwartz sequences
\newcommand{\seqs}{\mathcalligra{s}}

\begin{document}
The classical sequence spaces are:
\[
\seqf
\subseteq \seqs
\subseteq \seqcn
\subseteq \seqc
\subseteq \ell^\infty
\]
\end{document}
```

Beside that, there seem to be quite a bit of kerning issues...

Comment: I dont know the answer but `{\mathcalligra{c_0}}` looks better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I imagine that you are looking for a free solution, but it seems that getting a nice looking `f` glyph that matches the traditionally used `\ell`, and which is not confused with a function, is a rather difficult chore.

I suggest that you give a look to the *commercial* [MathTime Pro 2](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html#Complete_set_only_features) font set. It provides "Script" and "Curly Script" variants that have nice glyphs for all letters you need `f`, `s`, `c` and `l`.

Note: I have no relationship whatsoever with PCTeX. But after looking into this issue for a while, it seems this font provides a reasonable alternative from the *aesthetical* point of view, although it will be nice to see if someone has a free (as in beer and in speech) solution to this question.

Comment: thanks a lot for the hint. They look indeed promising, but as you said, a free solution would be much more desirable.

Comment: it seems that no free solutions shows up, so I will accept your answer. The fonts really look pretty...